# Download files with webview

Tags: android, android-webview

I want to download files with webview, but as soon as I click the download link, the application closes itself automatically.

```
mWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {

 public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {

          Request request = new Request( Uri.parse(url)); request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();

          request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);

          request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "download");

          DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

         dm.enqueue(request);
```

} });

Comment: Look in the logcat and tell us the exception.  Also tell which statement causes the exception.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView webView;
    private String WebUrl = "https://www.google.com";
    String FileName;
    String  URL;
    String Agent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl(WebUrl);

        webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {
                FileName = URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, getType(url));
                URL = url;
                Agent = userAgent;
                if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        startDownload(FileName, URL, Agent);
                    }else {
                        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},1001);
                    }
                }else {
                    startDownload(FileName, URL, Agent);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void startDownload(String filename, String url, String userAgent) {
        try {
            DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
            String cookie = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
            request.setTitle(filename)
                    .setDescription("Downloading")
                    .setMimeType(getType(url))
                    .setAllowedOverMetered(true)
                    .setAllowedOverRoaming(true)
                    .setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE | DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, filename);
            dm.enqueue(request);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Download Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            FileName = "";
            URL = "";
            Agent = "";

        }catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error Occured : "+e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private String getType(String link) {
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        MimeTypeMap mimeTypeMap = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        return mimeTypeMap.getExtensionFromMimeType(cr.getType(Uri.parse(link)));
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if(requestCode == 1001) {
            if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                if(!FileName.equals("") && !URL.equals("") && !Agent.equals("")){
                    startDownload(FileName, URL, Agent);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks to me that you posted the same code.

Comment: It is the same code as the code OP posted. So why did you post? Please tell the difference.

Comment: it seems your app crashes because you not implement run time permission checker and make sure you add manifest permission if you want to check try manually grant permission from the setting then try to download

Comment: About which permissions are you talking? The DownloadManager does not need any permission.

Comment: permission to write data into storage

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: Now I encountered an error I'm trying to download an excel file from the .aspx page, but it is downloading the extension as .aspx, not .xlsx

Comment: provide test download like

Comment: Can you give me details? I do not understand what should I do?

Comment: send download link I want to see what is happening

Comment: Response.ClearContent();Response.Clear();
Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachement;filename);
Response.Charset = "";
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
Response.BinaryWrite(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetPreamble());
Response.Charset = "utf-8";
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter ht = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
GridView1.RenderControl(ht);
Response.Write(sw.ToString());Response.End();

Comment: The code I use to download from this asp.net page